# MVC Refactoring Approach? How to introduce more generic functionality?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a complex wizard driven document creation application. I understand the initial domain's requirement and thus can create an explicit database model for this using explicit column names. Also I am a slight novice with MVC. I know that I will need to make the application more generic ie the Wizard will change, different attributes will need to be stored. My current view/instinct is to implement what is known at present using the most traditional techniques that the tools MVC/EF most closely support then refactor to support the more generic functionality at a later date using technologies such as XML features in SQL Server and WF Foundation etc. Doing all this now seems a big step.

So my question is about the virtue of keeping it simple to start with then refactor in the more sophisticated features later on, rather than building it generic to start with.

Thoughts and wisdom great appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It really depends on the application size imo

Comment: Thks for the reply. Probably about application 20 tables plus the membership tables.

Comment: Would you mind giving a little more information about the wizard itself? How many factors will influance the wizard process itself, how many factors inflances the document creation, what kind of document is it (invoice? report? diagrams? text? tabular? kind of data?). I'm just trying to get a better idea of what you are trying to acheive there. But in general, I would MOST OF THE TIME (not always) go out and do 1 fix wizard - document creation that has a lot of hardcoded information then proceed to make everything flexible and externalize what has to be dynamic and what-not.

Comment: 20 tables, however, could be better off starting dynamic right at the start. Specially if your database is created already.

Comment: If you choose the simple first path, just keep in mind during the whole process that this will not be the end code and that is needs to remain easy to read to allow refactoring.

Comment: The Wizard is really a collection of multiple forms onto the data object ie "Document Section". Some forms/Steps/Pages will be multirow and link to one table, another page may be a choice of standard answers which populate a seperate intersection table for "SelectedAnswers". I can see that I may well end up with an EAV or XML design in the Database. But my head is spinning on this at the moment since there are so many pros and cons for each. The 20 tables include all the lookups, so the data tables may only be about 5-10. I think your comment(3 back) seems to back up my instinct. Thks

Comment: Also I will need to tranform the persisted data to XML for conversion to Word. However, as I understand it, one can do this straight from relational data as easily as from chunks of stored XML.

Comment: Can you put the answer as an "answer" rather than a "comment" then I can mark you up. I cannot see how I can do this with comment. Really appreciate your help. Thks.

Comment: Of course. I was writting an actual full answer though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FEEL like in this situation (read OP comments), if you go for a simple "demo" version of your wizard with more hardcoded stuff then you will want in the end, you'll end up scrapping the demo instead of refactoring it. HOWEVER, I'm not saying it's a bad way to go.

From my point of view, theres 2 ways to aproach the developpement process of such an application.

- The first one is doing a quick sketch version of the application as mentionned above. Doing  so will make you realize the pros and cons of going in one or another direction, will make you realize things that has to be built one way rather then the other and all that kind of stuff. This is the "code monkey" method. Just type the damn code!
- The second one is going into more of a UML route and doing diagrams of exactly what you want. However, without much experience in UML designing, this may end up as a huge waste of time since you will go on and make your application, thinking you going everything figured out, then get to writting the code and realize there is stuff you didnt account for. This path should be the best route to go but a lack of experience doing this might cost you time and money.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes I am totally aware of UML, and am a big fan of modelling. However I am also are of "Analysis Paralysis". So thanks, your comments have been helpful.